# Better to use SERIAL PRIMARY KEY or GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY for primary key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, identity-column

Not sure which option is latest best practice? I read on on this tutorial that:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/

> PostgreSQL version 10 introduced a new constraint GENERATED AS
> IDENTITY that allows you to automatically assign a unique number to a
> column.
>
> The GENERATED AS IDENTITY constraint is the SQL standard-conforming
> variant of the good old SERIAL column.

In the example they use the identity as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE color (
    color_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    color_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

When you reference this table for a FOREIGN KEY as per the below:

```
CREATE TABLE pallet (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    color_1 REFERENCES color
    color_2 REFERENCES color
);
```

Will it know that the identity is the primary key now?:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Will it know that the identity is the primary key now?

No (and neither would a `serial` do that).

You need to define the primary key explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE color (
    color_id INT  primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    color_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

---

> Not sure which option is latest best practice?

It's recommended to use `identity` instead of `serial`.

[Quote from the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)

> For new applications, identity columns should be used instead.
> Why not serial?
> The serial types have some weird behaviors that make schema, dependency, and permission management unnecessarily cumbersome.

Finally, identity columns conform with the SQL standard, while `serial` is PostgreSQL dialect.